# C: I don't know what this mean "while(temp->next->next)"

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I've a struct linkedList like that

```c
typedef struct linkedList l_List;

struct linkedList{
  hash_It* item;     /*this is hashItem structure include key and value*/
  l_List* next;     /*next list                                       */  
};
```

and my question is: what `temp->next->next` mean?
I've suspected that temp datatype is `l_List*` instead of `l_List**` 
Why it's can use as level 2 pointer by that way?

cre:I found this code on another source

```c
l_List* temp = list;
    while (temp->next->next) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

Comment: Please read more about the [C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), in particular read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book. Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). With a modern [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info). Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website

Comment: C is case-sensitive: your `struct linkedList` isn't the same type as referred to by `LinkedList* temp`. Please post your **actual** program source code. If this is your actual program source code then you need to tidy it up first.

Comment: With a linked list (after it is created), the `->next` pointer will point to the next node in the list. So `->next->next` points to the 2nd node after the current node `temp`.

Comment: For your next question, please provide some [MRE] in it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why do you have to suspect anything? If you have that list, look at the code what `temp` is. There is no mentioning of `l_List**`.  Where did you get that? There is no level 2 pointer usage here. Finally, show the code (complete enough to be compilable) to us that you want an explanation for.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch a year ago I was banned for 6 months for advising the C books if someone did not know the basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an equivalent to

```c
l_List* find(l_list *temp)
{
    while (temp->next) 
    {
        l_list *temp1 = temp -> next;
        if(temp1 -> next == NULL)
            break; 
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return  temp;
}
```

It should help you to understand what it means.

```c
l_list *temp1 = temp -> next -> next;
```

is the same as

```c
l_list *temp1 = temp -> next;
temp1 = temp1 -> next;
```